# Xl.generateReport file location does not create excel report on server

Tags: excel, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, reporting

So i am using selenium Webdriver+maven+TestNg.
I am trying to generate excel report using XL.generateReport method.Below is the code.

```
 public void SendMail() throws Exception
{
    String userDirector = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    
    String resultFile = userDirector + "/Reports/";
    
    Xl.generateReport(resultFile,"excel-report.xlsx");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    
    Date dt = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
    String strDate= formatter.format(dt); 
    
    //authentication info
            final String username = "abc1@test.com";
            final String password = "pass@123";
            String fromEmail = "abc2@test.com";
            String toEmail = "abc3@test.com";
            String ccEmail= "ravi@test.com";
            String ccEMail2="Rajeev@test.com";
            
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            
            Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
                }
            });
            //Start our mail message
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            try {
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
                msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
                //msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(ccEmail));
                msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(ccEMail2));
                msg.setSubject("Test Execution Report on "+strDate);
                
                Multipart emailContent = new MimeMultipart();
                
                //Text body part
                MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                
                textBodyPart.setText("Hello, Good day! \n"
                        + "\n"
                        + "All scenarios have been executed. Please find the attached report of the execution.  \n"
                        + "\n"
                        + "Thanks,\n"
                        + "Mahesh.");
                
                //Attachment body part.
                MimeBodyPart pdfAttachment = new MimeBodyPart();
                pdfAttachment.attachFile(resultFile+ "excel-report.xlsx");
                
                //Attach body parts
                emailContent.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
                emailContent.addBodyPart(pdfAttachment);
                
                //Attach multi-part to message
                msg.setContent(emailContent);
                
                Transport.send(msg);
                System.out.println("Sent message");
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

So above code is basically going to create a report and store in Reports folder of my project directory.
Further I am using a code to email this generated excel on my email ID.
The above code works fine for me on my local machine.

The problem is when I put this code on server.
I am creating a Runner JAR file and I create a folder with this Runner JAR file, Reports folder and TestNg.xml with some other folder to upload image and stuff.
When I execute the JAR on server, excel report is not getting generated and no email is received with report attached. Same JAR does not work on any other machine that has Microsoft office as well as JAVA on their machine.

I am not sure if there is any path related issue when I run the JAR on server.
On the server , we do not have Microsoft Office installed. But I would like a code that works fine irrespective of whether we have Microsoft office installed or not.

One more addition to this is, I am also creating .html report with same path that is used for excel and this works fine on local as well as on server. HTML report is generated under Reports folder accurately.

Also I have tried changing the excel report path to my local machine folder as well as to the path of the server folder where i have kept the package. But nothing worked

So please help and let me know for solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, just so I understand there is no problem with Excel? So why tag Excel?

Comment: Thought that its reporting in excel sheet so tagged it.

Comment: So what did the result look like in Excel? Duplicates? Blank?

Comment: The result looks fine in excel when I execute the code/project from my eclipse. Excel has a summary, pie chart, Testcase name, testcase pass/fail, execution time, date. But when I execute the Project runner file then this excel file itself does not get generated.